# how to show text in input field "password" and after typing on it switch again to password view

Tags: javascript, html, input-field

i have some login with password field:

```
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Password" maxlength="40" required style="width: 130px; font-size: 10px;" />
```

as output i have password field with value "Password" which is showed just like   `"********"`, what is
clearly. 
but i want to see it as a text "Password" and just after typing inside show `********`. how to do that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `placeholder` attribute.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdtGd/).

Comment: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="40" required style="width: 130px; font-size: 10px;" /> so???

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs try it and see :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password" maxlength="40" required="" style="width: 130px; font-size: 10px;">
```

It should be noted that if value attribute is before placeholder attribute, it will take priority and you will see the default value set. (which for a password field, does not make a lot of sense to me).

Comment: Yes true. Just noticed that value would take priority only when before placeholder. May be it is new only to me. Still thought I would share :)